# How do I play my music library on a Chromecast TV?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, music, chromecast

How do I play the music in my Music app on a Chromecast TV? In the YouTube app, I can select to play a video to Chromecast. In Pandora, I can select to play a channel to Chromecast. In the music app, I can select a connected Bluetooth device as the output channel. But there is not an option to play music in the Music app to Chromecast. How can I play music from the Music app to Chromecast? Does it require a separate Google music app or something?

iOS 10.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to a Chromecast generally does not involve your device streaming to the Chromecast - you need to run some sort of server to stream from a local computer (or the Chrome extension that mirrors a computer screen to the Chromecast.)

When you use apps on iOS to cast, it just tells the Chromecast where on the internet to stream from - and the internet service must support Chromecast.

So what you want to do with your music app can’t be done. Depending on where you keep your music there may be some solutions. For example, if you have a computer with your music on it, you could install Plex as a server, and the Plex app on your iOS device.

Comment: So there are no apps that can read music and speak the Chromecast protocol? There are FTP server apps where you can connect to your phone over FTP. Maybe something like that which tells Chromecast to look for music at `http://192.168.1.2`?